# How can I check if an id is present with Perl's HTML::TreeBuilder?

Tags: html, perl

I have the following file:

```
<p>
<a href="a1">A1</a>
<a href="a2">A2</a>
<a id="a3">A3</a>
<a href="a4">A4</a>
</p>
```

I need to skip the `a` tags from within the list obtained by `$para->look_down("tag"=>'a');`, which have an id attribute equal to some value.
I am doing:

```
$str = '';
$str = $anchor->attr('id');
if ($str != 'a3') {
    last;
}
```

This does not work when `id` attribute is not defined: it breaks out of the loop. How to do this?

Comment: Note that you should be using "ne" as the "not equal" operator as you are comparing strings, not numbers

Comment: @RC ok. but what about the rest?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure that I understand your question and that's why I didn't provide an answer.  What do you mean it doesn't work?  Do you get an error or a warning?  If I'm understanding correctly, you might want to do:  if ($str ne "" && $str ne "a3") { last; }  of if you want to continue the loop and "skip" then use next; instead of last;

Comment: it worked. that was the problem.

Comment: I'll post my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean it doesn't work? Do you get an error or a warning?

If I'm understanding correctly, you might want to do:

```
if ($str ne "" && $str ne "a3") 
{ 
    last; 
}
```

Note, the use of `ne` for "not equal" instead of the numeric `!=`.

Also, if you want to continue the loop instead of jumping out, you can "skip" by using `next;` instead of `last;`.

Answer (score 0):

[RC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101179/how-can-i-check-if-an-id-is-present-with-perls-htmltreebuilder/2101434#2101434) will give you "Use of uninitialized value ..." warnings if you are running with `use strict; use warnings;` (which you should *always* have at the top of every Perl file). Instead of checking for the empty string, check if it is defined:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (... something ...)
{
    my $str = $anchor->attr('id');
    next unless defined $str and $str eq 'a3';

    # now process $str
}
```